# How do I scale a Mobject using a Manim updater?

Tags: scale, manim, updaters

1. I can scale a Square mobject as follows with `self.play()`/`Scene.play()`:

   ```py
   square = Square(fill_color=RED, fill_opacity=1)

   self.play(square.animate.scale(3))
   self.wait(3)
   ```

   [image]
2. But I cannot achieve the `scale` behaviour as above using this simple  `add_updater` method. All I get is a blank screen:

   ```py
   square = Square(fill_color=RED, fill_opacity=1)

   def scale_up(mob, dt):
       mob.scale(2*dt)

   square.add_updater(scale_up)
   self.add(square)
   self.wait(3)
   ```

### Questions

1. How can I achieve the behaviour of No 1 above with `add_updater`, or other updater techniques?
2. I know that I can successfully animate an item with updater methods - such as doing `mobject.shift()` - even *without* using `self.play()`/`Scene.play()`. Can the behaviour of No. 1 above be achieved *without* using the `Scene.play()` method?
3. It appears that you can `.scale()` an object with scene updaters, instead of Mobject updaters. Why?

Comment: It appears that `mob.scale(2*dt)` instantly shrinks your square to almost zero. According to the manual, `dt` is the time in seconds between two frames, a very small number.
Using `mob.scale(1.02)` instead slowly increases the size of the square, by two percent at each update iteration, if I understand correctly.